# Publishing a paper in my own workshop

Tags: workshop, chairing

I'm co-organizing a workshop in conjunction of a leading conference. Since the topic is quite close to my work I'm considering to submit my own paper to the workshop.

Given the fact that I'm serving as one of the workshop chairs (and the review process is single-blind)- Is it ok to submit my own paper there?

Comment: Ask your fellow workshop organisers. Ask yourself if one of your students shouldn't give the talk.

Comment: Yes, but try to avoid that the majority of the papers in the workshop's proceedings are co-authored by the organizers. It may seem from the outside like the organizers are trying to save a workshop that would otherwise not receive many submissions.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can submit, but if you are concerned about fairness, as seems obviously true since you are asking, then you may need to leave all reviewing to others.

You might, however, also consult the wider conference committee to see if they have any reservations or suggestions.

But such workshops are intended for a relatively small group of very interested people, of whom you are one. And it is hard, in such groups, to guarantee that no reviewer knows the author.

If you are, however, a very senior academic, you might also consider not submitting and leaving the floor open to the less experienced.

Comment: +1. Isn't the case same as submitting a paper to a journal where the author is either EiC or an editorial board member?

Comment: I see a difference in the fact that the reviewing is not fully anonymous and therefore there might be a bias in favor of the workshop chair.

Answer (score 6):

It's OK in the sense that you won't get into trouble for this.

But from the perspective of an uninvolved observer, people might be slightly confused how the paper ended up being accepted, specifically, if it was indeed assessed with the same standards as other papers at the workshop. As one might say in certain parts of Germany, the situation has a [Geschmäckle](https://educalingo.com/en/dic-de/geschmackle) (a "weird taste", hinting at something potentially fishy going on).